# How to only show TOP N in table

Tags: powerbi

I have a simple table with a name field and a count(distinct) field and I am trying to figure out how to show only the TOP N records based on the count(distinct) column, the sorting and the count works great I just cannot find the option to limit it to top N records

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solutions I know are:

1. Use RANK calculation, then inserting a filter
2. Create a new table in dax using the TOPN function

https://dax.guide/topn/

```
NewTable = TOPN(100, YourTable
               , YourTable[ColumnToOrder]
               , DESC)
```